# Ref-qualifiers in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there any stable version of Visual Studio that supports ref-qualified member functions in C++?

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) says they're not supported in Visual Studio 2013, but it doesn't go into the various updates of VS13.

On the other hand, [this](http://herbsutter.com/2013/11/18/visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp/) says they made it into a CTP back in 2013.